# Convert String to Eloquent functions

Tags: php, json, laravel, api, eloquent

I am building an API with laravel, so I am trying to pass Laravel's Eloquent functions as string and execute them in the controller, actually I am sending a JSON object but I am converting it to a string in backend, here is what I tried to do

API URL with parameters:
http://www.example.com/api/articles?parameters={"orderByDesc":"'created_at'", "limit":"2"}

Controller side:

```
$json = json_decode(request('parameters'), TRUE);

$query = '';

foreach ($json as $function => $value){

    $query .= $function.'('.$value.')->';

}

$query = $query.'get();';

return $query;
```

Output:

```
orderByDesc('created_at')->limit(2)->get();
```

Now how can I execute this string as code on the model, example:

```
$articles = Article::orderByDesc('created_at')->limit(2)->get();
```

I couldn't concatenate like this: **Article::.$query**
And I can't use PHP's **eval()**

The idea is to use Laravel's Eloquent functions inside a JSON object and pass them in one URL parameter.

Thanks

Comment: this is one most horrified thing I have ever seen. why someone do that

Comment: I see your point @TeomanTıngır but this is an internal API, that mostly Laravel developers will use

Comment: This is wrong at so many places. Why not break parameters (which is JSON in your case) as standard query parameters. then construct a proper JSON in your controller and take it forward. If you really have to send JSON, send it in a POST request instead of query params in GET. Also using string concatenation to build an executable code is so hacky. Please don't do that.

Comment: @Prakhar I will consider this too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try this.

```
$json = json_decode(request('parameters'), true);

$query = Article::query();

foreach($json as $function => $value){
    $query->{$function}($value);
}

$query = $query->get();

return $query;
```

You can run function on object with `->{$func_name}` syntax

> **Edit:** You can pass multiple arguments too. But you can check if whether value is array or not:

```
foreach($json as $function => $value){
    if(is_array($value)) {
        $query->{$function}(...$value);
    } else {
        $query->{$function}($value);
    }
}
```

In this case you can have: `{"orderByDesc":"'created_at'", "limit":"2", "where": ["column_name", "LIKE", "%SOME_STRING"]}` and it will generate query equivalent to: `->where('column_name', 'LIKE', '%SOME_STRING')`